# How to initiate a variable in dust.js at run time?

Tags: node.js, dust.js

How to initiate a variable inside the dust js template.

Problem :

```
//want to initiate a variable like flag = false;
{#orderItemData}
    {^isTicketDisabled}
        //assign flag = true;
    {/isTicketDisabled}
{/orderItemData}
//I need to process here on the basis of flag.
```

How can I do. Please help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different solutions. I'll give you one that follows the letter of your question, and one that I think is more elegant that accomplishes the same thing.

### Set Data Into the Context

If you really want to set data onto the context based on your Dust template, you could write a helper to do so. It might look something like this:

```
dust.helpers.addToContext = function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  var key = context.resolve(params.key);
  var value = context.resolve(params.value);

  // The easiest thing to do is just to add this value to the context globals
  // so that it's accessible everywhere
  context.global[key] = value;
  return chunk;
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
{@addToContext key="flag" value="true"/}
```

### Use a Context Helper

What it really seems like you want, however, is a way to say "if any tickets were disabled, do something". That's what context helpers are for-- they're a transformation of the existing data you have. You might add a helper to your context like this:

```
{
  orders: [{ orderItemData: { ... } },
           { orderItemData: { ... } },
           { orderItemData: { ... } }]
  isTicketForOrderDisabled: function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
    // Helpers can return true or false to determine the rendering
    // of their block, among many other things. This is a simple example
    return context.get('isTicketDisabled');
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
{#orders}
  {#orderItemData}{! Display some things !}{/orderItemData}
  {#isTicketForOrderDisabled:orderItemData}{! Passing a single order to the helper !}{/isTicketForOrderDisabled}
{/orders}
```

So now you haven't had to alter your context, but you can still get all the information you need out of your existing data.